# Update sprites nested in groups

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I update or manipulate a sprite nested in several groups?

I first tried to add the "enterFrame" event directly to the desired class with the sprite (without success)

My code

```
local box = {}

-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

function box:new(  )

    local group = display.newGroup()

    local image = display.newImage("crate.png")

    group:insert(image)

    function group:update()
        image.rotation = image.rotation + 1
    end

    return group
end

return box
```

Second I though of adding a

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame)
```

in my scene, then looping through the groups added to the scene (`scene.view`) and call a custom update-function there that sends the update forward until it reaches my class. However I have not found a way of checking if the group has a update method or not. Now I just call update even if the group does not have it.

```
function enterFrame (event)
    local group = scene.view
    for i=1,group.numChildren do
        group[i]:update()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

local box = {}

You can try this simple solution

```
-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

function box:new(  )

    local group = display.newGroup()

    local image = display.newImage("crate.png")

    group:insert(image)
    group.isThereUpdate = true
    // or group.isThereUpdate = false

    function group:update()
        image.rotation = image.rotation + 1
    end

    return group
end

return box


function enterFrame (event)
    local group = scene.view
    for i=1,group.numChildren do
        if group[i].isThereUpdate then
            group[i]:update()
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Works well, you do not know how to use `Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame)` to set the listener directly to the update function `group:update` ?

Comment: You mean, something like Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", group:update ) ?

Comment: Yes "something like that". It gives me a `function arguments expected near ')'`-error trying that code inside my new() method

Comment: I think, there is no way to do that. So you should use a general enterFrame listener. If this is a problem for performance, you can use timer instead of enterFrame. And in that timer, you may call your function in every 100ms or whatever.

Comment: just realized, I guess you can use :

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", function() group:new() end )

Comment: `Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", function() group:update() end)` works perfect. Do you know if and how I should remove the eventlistner? Or is it removed when I remove the object or perhaps the scene?

Comment: On second thought, if I switch scene I need to unload the eventListner so I does not run in the background. However, setting the eventListner directly in the box class makes it hard to remove it on scene switch. Think I will stay with your first answer!

Comment: I made a typo up there, sorry for that ( update() not new() ) ^^
You can do this similar to that :

Runtime:addEventListener( "myEventType", myListener ) 
 
-- Sometime later, create an event and dispatch it 
local event = { name="myEventType", target=Runtime } 
Runtime:dispatchEvent( event )


And you may also have an array for such event objects. For event object name and target proprties are must

Comment: Ok. thanks. Any thought on how and where to remove this listener?